# Regex - Look for a particular word in a string either preceding or succeeding with nothing or any non-alphabet

Tags: regex

Search string "test" which can be   preceding or succeeding with non-alphabet like '123test123' or '-test/' but it should not be like 'ABCtestABC'

Valid String:

```
https://us-east-2.console.aws.amazon.com/ec2/testify
```

Invalid Strings:

```
https://us-east-2.console.aws.amazon.com/ec2/test
https://us-east-2.console.aws.amazon.com/ec2/test123
https://us-east-2.console.aws.amazon.com/ec2/123test123
```

I used

```
 MyRegex= @"([^a-zA-Z])test([^a-zA-Z])"
```

But problem is when the path ends with `test` then it is not working.

Comment: Please show us what you tried and how it didn't work

Comment: MyRegex= @"([^a-zA-Z])test([^a-zA-Z])"                                       But problem is when the path ends with test then it is not working

Answer (score 0):

Your regex is matching and consuming characters with the `[^A-Za-z]` negated character classes.

You need to use lookarounds:

```
(?<![a-zA-Z])test(?![a-zA-Z])
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/3VRA4R/1).

**Details**

- `(?<![a-zA-Z])` - a negative lookbehind that matches a location in a string that is not immediately preceded with an ASCII letter
- `test` - a word
- `(?![a-zA-Z])`  - a negative lookahead that matches a location in a string that is not immediately followed with an ASCII letter.